# Linq фильтрация результата

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Столкнулся с проблемой делаю запрос к БД

```
public class LinkTabProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int CatalogSubSectionId { get; set; }
    public CatalogSubSection CatalogSubSection { get; set; }
}

var result = DataContext.Product                    
                .Include(o => o.Offers)
                        .ThenInclude(p => p.Prices)
                            .ThenInclude(t => t.Type)
                .Include(p => p.Brand)
                .Include(tb=>tb.LinkTabProductCategories)
                .Where( p=>p.LinkTabProductCategories **???** == id)
                .ToList();
```

И нужно отфильтровать, получив только те объекты которые имеют связь с записями таблицы `LinkTabProductCategories` у которых поле `CatalogSubSectionId`  равняется заданной переменно `Id`.

Так же буду очень благодарен за наводку на документацию (или подобного)  по `Linq` кроме `MSDN` соответственно.

Спасибо

Comment: `.Where(p => p.LinkTabProductCategories.Any())`? Или я не понял сути вопроса

Comment: Получаем список объектов Product ,
у которого есть свойство типа  List<LinkTabProductCategories>, 
а у LinkTabProductCategories - есть свойство CatalogSubSectionId  по которому  и надо отфильтровать

как то так

Comment: `.Any()` как раз вам подойдет, он возвращает `true`, если имеется хотя бы один элемент, проверяйте.

Comment: По Linq почитайте, например, Албахари

Comment: Албахари скачал 

Any -  даст наличие,  а мне нужно чтоб значение свойства  == переменной Id

Comment: Ну тогда `.Any(c => c.CatalogSubSectionId == id)`

Comment: `.Where( p=>p.LinkTabProductCategories.Any(l=>l.CatalogSubSectionId  == id))` ?

Comment: Парни спасибо, 
то что нужно скачал пару книжек,  доку бы  конечно поудобнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод расширения `Any(predicate)` — он возвращает `true`, если в последовательности существует хотя бы один элемент, удовлетворяющий условию `predicate`:

```
.Where(p => p.LinkTabProductCategories.Any(c => c.CatalogSubSectionId == id))
```